# Borel sets. Need to prove.

Tags: probability, borel-sets

I need to prove that set $(1,4)$ is Borel set. Actually, I have no idea how to do it. I was looking for theory. And find something.

Let $I={(1,4), a<b, \text{ and } a,b \in R}$
Than $(1,4)= \cup_{n=1}^\infty (1, 4-\frac{1}{n}], a<b$.

and it is a proof? How I should prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of Borel set? It seems that you think of them as elements of $\sigma$-algebra generated left-open/right-closed intervals like $(a,b]$. Then what you mention is indeed a proof that $(1,4)$ is a Borel set. That "definition" is okay, but it is better to define them as elements of $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets (as you meet in the answer of Fred). Then your definition becomes a theorem. If it is unclear which definition is practicized then it is not possible to recognize "proofs".

Answer (score 2):

The Borel sets in $ \mathbb R$ are generated by the open sets in $ \mathbb R$ and $(1,4)$ is open !

Comment: Than what about set [1,4]?  how to prove it is a Borel set?

Comment: The complement of $[1,4]$ is open !

Comment: and that is it? Enough to show this and nothing more to explain? I didn't think it is that easy...

Comment: If $A$ is a member of a $ \sigma-$ algebra, then the complement of $A$ is also a  member of the $ \sigma-$ algebra

Comment: Ok, what about $\mathbb{N}$  set. How to prove it is a Borel set?

Comment: $ \mathbb N$ is closed, hence the complement of $ \mathbb N$  is open ....